# Update view model through ajax request through click binding in knockout

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I have a view model binded with sample data at first, The binding works fine.

Here is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/46LXU/

However if i use a click binding to get the same data from server, I get the data but i couldn't able to use that to load it to view model.

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" data-bind="click: function(data) { selectionChanged( 1 ) }">Sample Data 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-bind="click: function(data) { selectionChanged( 2 ) }">Sample Data 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-bind="click: function(data) { selectionChanged( 3 ) }">Sample Data 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Each click above loads new data from server through following jQuery Post.

```
my.vm.selectionChanged = function (){
 //This loads new data from server
 jQuery.post(
      MyAjax.ajaxurl,
      {
          action : 'rcv_getpost',
          cvid : 2,
      },
      function( response ) {
           return {
             data: response 
            };
       }
    //Response now have the new data. How to load the data and to update it with view? 
    );      

my.vm.load();
}
```

My Actual View Model

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {


var my = { }; //my namespace

my.sampleData = (function (my) {    

    var dataary = {
  "sections": [
    {
      "section_name": "Qualifications",
      "data": "Sample Data",
      "key": "qual"
    },
    {
      "section_name": "Interests",
      "data": "These are my interests",
      "key": "int"
    },
    {
      "section_name": "Referance",
      "data": "This Is my referance",
      "key": "ref"
    }
  ]
};
     return {
             data: dataary
            };
})(my);

    // Product construction
    var Section = function () {
        this.section_name = ko.observable();
        this.data = ko.observable();
        this.key = ko.observable();
        this.prevent = ko.observable();
    };


    my.vm = {
        // observable array of sections
        sections: ko.observableArray([]),
        // loading the observable array with sample data
        load: function () {
            console.log(my.sampleData.data.sections);
            $.each(my.sampleData.data.sections, function (i, p) {
                    my.vm.sections.push(new Section()
                        .section_name(p.section_name)
                        .data(p.data)
                        .key(i)
                    )
            });
        }

    }; // End of My.VM


   my.vm.load();
   ko.applyBindings(my.vm);




});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your click handler:

```
  function( response ) {
       my.vm.load({
         data: response 
        });
   }
```

and remove the other call to `load()`. Remember that AJAX actions are *asynchronous*; their callbacks can't return a value.

In your VM:

```
    load: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        my.vm.sections([]); // assuming you want to replace your sample data rather than append to it
        $.each(data.sections, function (i, p) {
```

And finally:

```
my.vm.load(my.sampleData);
ko.applyBindings(my.vm);
```

Comment: I just can't figure this out, http://jsfiddle.net/46LXU/2/ where am i doing it wrong?

Comment: You've got a syntax error (unmatched `);`) and for some reason JQuery is throwing errors in the fiddle context, making it very difficult to debug. Fix the syntax error and try setting up the fiddle with an older version of jQuery.

Comment: I got it working on my application, Followed your approach. However i couldn't make it work on Jsfiddle. http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html I think i am messing with Ajax API requests of jsfiddle

Comment: The AJAX problem is probably the result of the same-origin policy; code loaded from jsfiddle can't make AJAX requests to other sites.